# How to acces the src to a td element that has id?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Table]

I have a table, and each cell has it's a unique ID, how to access the src value and change it?

```
<tr><td id="ROOM11"><img src="01.png"></td><td id="ROOM12"
```

This JavaScript code try to access the src but it returns with null value:

```
let cellid = document.querySelector("#ROOM11");
console.log(cellid.getAttribute('id'));//I manage to access the ID: returns  ROOM11
cellid.setAttribute('src',02.png'); //returns with an error
cellid.getAttribute('src'); //returns with null
```

I maybe need to access the child element but I don't know how to access it?

Comment: `setAttribute('src',02.png');`: you're getting an error because you're missing a quote around `02.png`

Comment: you are not targeting the `img` you are targeting the `td` use`let cellid = document.querySelector("#ROOM11 > img");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector to `#ROOM11 img`. `#ROOM11` by itself will only select the element with the `id` `ROOM11`.

```js
let cellid = document.querySelector("#ROOM11 img");
console.log(cellid)

cellid.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="ROOM11"><img src="01.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```